# Join is not working properly

Tags: php, sql, join

I am new to SQL and trying to fetch data using join. Don't know what I am doing wrong. I have two tables.

---

Table `record`

`recordID|activityName|userID
1       |  sale      | 5
2       |  call      | 5
3       | contact    | 5`

Table `activity`

`activityID|activityData|userID
 1         | 50         | 5 
 2         | 70         | 5
 3         | xyz        | 5`

Result should be

`recordID|activityName|activityData|userID
 1       | sale       | 50         | 5
 2       | call       | 70         | 5
 3       | contact    | xyz        | 5`

But it returns

`recordID|activityName|activityData|userID
 1       | sale       | 50         | 5
 2       | call       | 70         | 5
 3       | contact    | xyz        | 5
 1       | sale       | 50         | 5
 2       | call       | 70         | 5
 3       | contact    | xyz        | 5
 1       | sale       | 50         | 5
 2       | call       | 70         | 5
 3       | contact    | xyz        | 5`

`SELECT * FROM tblrecord tr, tblactivity ta WHERE  tr.userID = ta.userID AND  tr.userID = '5'`

Why is it repeating the result.

PS. userID is the only common field, the activityID and recordID can be different.

Comment: You asked to get all combinations of activities and records which correspond to `userId=5` all combinations would be record 1 with activity 1, record 1 with activity 2, record 1 with activity 3 ... and so on.  If this is not what you need, then you must tell us what you DO need and we can tell you why your query was wrong.

Comment: I just want to show data of both tables without repeating

Answer (score 3):

First, follow a simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Second, you seem to want a join on `recordId` and `activityId`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblrecord tr JOIN
     tblactivity ta 
     ON  tr.userID = ta.userID AND
         tr.recordId = ta.activityId
WHERE tr.userID = 5;
```

Also, don't use single quotes if the value is really a number.

Comment: Well I'd disagree with the rule "never use commas". Instead, follow the rule "if the term *cross product* or *cartesian product* are unknown to you or you know that they are not what you need, do not use commas in the `FROM` clause"

Comment: Actually the userID is the only common field. A user can have multiple records and the activityID and recordID can be different.

Comment: @apokryfos If you intend to do a cross product, you should use an explicit `CROSS JOIN`.  Commas in the from clause died with ANSI-92.

Comment: @apokryfos . . . *Never* use commas.  Use `cross join` if that is your intention.

Comment: @SamB . . . Perhaps you should ask another question with better sample data.  Revising this question would be rude, because it would invalidate the answers, which seem to be correct.  Changing a question *after* there are answer can lead to downvotes on the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Add

> GROUP BY userID, activityID

to your query.